# Mac OS Snow Leopard freezes

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, freeze

I got this error:

> Timexxxx In 'CFPasteboardCopyData',
>   file
>   /SourceCache/CF/CF-550.13/AppServices.subproj/CFPasteboard.c,
>   line 1951, during lock, spin lock
>   0x15457a0c8 has value 0xf0000000,
>   which is neither locked nor unlocked.
>   The memory has been smashed.

My Mac freezes except the mouse and keyboard. What is happening and how can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is to go to Applications->Utilities->Disk Utility, highlight your harddrive and "Repair Permissions".  If you can't do that on a normal boot, you might try if from "Safe Mode" (hold the "Shift Key" down while booting) or boot from your OS X DVD (hold the "c" key down while booting to boot from the CD/DVD drive).  Then, after a few steps you should be able to access the Disk Utility.